# HDD not recognized by Disk Management

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

*I realize there are many different topics on the subject, but after reading through pages of them, I don't think I found any that is precisely like mine (could be wrong).*

So I'm trying to install a second HDD to my PC (it's not new, no idea if it was properly formatted). It **is** recognized by the BIOS, seems to be functioning (spins, is warm), but neither Disk Management, nor Device Manager seem to detect it. Any ideas why?

Seagate 1TB SATA, Windows 8.1

Thank you.

Comment: When you indicate that Disk Management does not detect it, do you mean, it's not even listed in the list of devices?  I assume you have verified that the SATA cable isn't defective?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes to both. The cable is functioning and the HDD is not even listed.

Comment: How about a screenshot of what is displayed within Disk Management?

Comment: Try an OS on USB drive, such as a Linux Live distro, to see if it's a Windows issue  or if another tool, such as gparted, can see the HDD. If so, perhaps it can be formatted NTFS.

Comment: Use dban to wipe the drive, then it will show in Disk Management...you do not have to wipe the entire drive, abort the wipe after 5 minutes should do....https://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/

Comment: Dban tutorial...https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-erase-a-hard-drive-using-dban-2619148

Comment: @Moab Thanks, will try that. I'm kinda scared of messing it up and deleting my main drive as well. Could it be possible to disconnect it and boot into Dban with only the drive I want to wipe connected? You know, for my own peace of mind.

Comment: "possible to disconnect it and boot into Dban with only the drive I want to wipe connected?" Yes, good idea, it is what I do.

Comment: @Moab: I've been trying for a while to run DBAN without success. I tried installing an USB with Rufus and with UUI, but neither seems to be recognized by the BIOS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Windows disk management has a habit of not listing devices that are formatted in ways it doesn't understand. Underlying Windows OS *probably* does see it if the BIOS does.

Try using lower level tools (fdisk ?), possibly on a linux system as mentioned above, or something which will wipe the first gigabyte of the drive (from Linux, dd if=/dev/zero ... sure there are options for Windows). You need to kill off the existing partitioning (sometimes inaccurately called MBR). Once it's not partitioned at all, disk management will consent to let you play.

Comment: I tried to boot a Linux distro and format with gparted, but it doesn't seem to recognize it either. It only sees the pendrive I'm booting Linux from.